# Showing several alert views consecutively: only the last one shows

Tags: ios, objective-c

I updated the question a bit with a very simple setup.

In appdelegate.h/m,

```
@property() UIAlertView *dialog;

-(void) showDialog:(NSString *)message {
   if (!dialog) {
      dialog=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:xx];
   }
   [dialog performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(show) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
}

-(void) dismissDialog {
  if(dialog) {
    [dialog dismissWithClickedbuttonIndex:0 animated:YES];
    dialog=nil;
  }
}
```

In viewcontroller.m

on button click

```
-(IBAction) clicked:(id)sender {

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  AppDelegate *_app = xxx;
  [_app showDialog:@"start1"];
  sleep(10);
  [_app dismissSyncDialog];

  [_app showSyncDialog:@"start2"];
  sleep(10);
  [_app dismissSyncDialog];

  [_app showSyncDialog:@"start3"];
  sleep(10);
  [_app dismissSyncDialog];
});
}
```

Only the last "start3" will show after a long time.

The behavior looks like the main thread is frozen, so that "start3" only appears after the thread is done.

Is there anyway to deal with this problem? Thanks.

Comment: First calling of showSyncDialog is executed in main thread or background thread?

Comment: It's in main thread. It will show without problem.

Answer (score 0):

Move [_app showSyncDialog:@"start"]; inside dispatch async.... If the alertview is presented on any other thread than main, it will cause the UI to hang

Comment: this will cause "start" disappear too. only "start3" will show.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for getting main thread.

```
double delayInSeconds = 1.0;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    // some stuff 1

    [self dismissSyncDialog];
    [self showSyncDialog:@"start2"];

    // some other stuff 2

    [self dismissSyncDialog];
    [self showSyncDialog:@"start3"];

    // some other stuff 3

    [self dismissSyncDialog];
});
```